# Select student do most of the project in least amount of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 2 tables, `STUDENT(stu_id, name)` and `PROJECT(project_id, name)`, linked together by `TASK(stu_id, project_id, duration)`, how can I find student with the number of projects is the largest while the duration of all that projects is the least? I've already tried this, but it's definitely wrong, since it find `MAX COUNT PROJECT` then join with `MIN SUM DURATION`, not `MAX COUNT PROJECT AND MIN SUM DURATION`

```
--WRONG
SELECT S.stu_id, S.stu_name
FROM STUDENT AS S
LEFT JOIN TASK AS T
ON S.stu_id = T.stu_id
GROUP BY S.stu_id, S.stu_name
HAVING COUNT(T.project_id) >= ALL(
                        SELECT COUNT(T1.project_id)
                        FROM TASK AS T1
                        GROUP BY T1.stu_id
                        )
AND SUM(T.duration) <= ALL(
                    SELECT SUM(T2.duration)
                    FROM TASK AS T2
                    GROUP BY T2.stu_id
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I find student with the number of projects is the largest while the duration of all that projects is the least?

This sounds like aggregation and limiting:

```
select top (1) stu_id, count(*) as num_projects, sum(duration) as total_duration
from task
group by stu_id
order by count(*) desc, sum(duration) asc;
```